# Yii 2 kartik\tree\TreeView ошибка Getting unknown property: yii\\web\\User::username

Tags: yii2

ставлю tree-manager от катрика

http://demos.krajee.com/tree-manager

но при попытке добавления нового корня получаю Getting unknown property: yii\web\User::username

при этом установление dektrium\user и залогинен как админ. их как-то подружить надо или проблема в другом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

изменить или удалить в модели

```
public function isDisabled()
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->username !== 'admin') {
        return true;
    }
    return parent::isDisabled();
}
```